# Simplest way to use JPA with my GWT application

Tags: gwt, jpa, rpc

I'd like to create a simple Google Web Toolkit application which makes uses RPCs.  For persistence, I'd like to use something like the Java Persistence API.

Does this mean I have to use an application server like Glassfish? or can I stick with a simple web container?

In terms of concrete libraries, how should I proceed?  TopLink? Hibernate? ...

Answer (score 3):

I believe the GWT RPC stuff is implemented as simple servlets.  Assuming that, you totally can use JPA in a web container like Tomcat and don't need a full blown J2EE app server.

To do that, you will need to do a bit of manual setup to make access to the PersistenceContext simpler.  Hibernate suggests using ThreadLocal, and I have an entry on my blog that details how I did that for Tomcat [here](http://www.naildrivin5.com/daveblog5000/?p=39)

Answer (score 2):

I would personally recommend Glassfish, as being more stable, better implemented and generally higher quality that Tomcat. I don't want to start a flame war (by saying that putting J2EE into Tomcat is like putting lipstick on a pig), but I will tell you how we deploy all of our applications:

We use Glassfish as the web container, TopLink as the persistence provider, generally connected to a MySQL 5 database. We use the JPA POJOs all the way from the EJB layer, through the web tier, and the GWT layer as well, via RPC. We also use Stripes and JSPs for all the presentation logic that doesn't require AJAX functionality. We've never had any problems with this approach, and have so far done at least 10 large-scale projects this way. It's the best architecture that we've had to date, and we've had a lot (tomcat, jboss, hibernate, struts, spring, etc, etc, etc).

Comment: How can i use JPA POJOS through the web GWT layer. I have problem with serialization - please help me my friend !

Answer (score 1):

You can user any container you like, i mean servlet and jpa containers.

The key point is that GWT doesn't suport jpa, so you have to use DTO design parten.
This will keep everything organized and you will not have problems with lazy loading.